# extracting data from xml file which is not in the table and having namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

I am having problem in fetching data from a xml file which needs to get validate against XSD first then I need to fetch some data from it and then insert that fetched data and the xml file into a table.

somehow I validate that xml but now its not fetching data from it.

```
 SELECT extractvalue(Value(x),'NewBusinessApplication/ApplicationRq/ApplInfo/APPLNO/text()')
   AS applno              --fetching required data from XML
     ,extractvalue(Value(x),'NewBusinessApplication/ApplicationRq/ApplInfo/APPL_DT/text()')
   AS appl_date           --to insert into adv_applications table
     ,extractvalue(Value(x),'NewBusinessApplication/TransactionHeader/SRC_SYS_CD/text()')  
   AS src_cd
 INTO l_app_no_xml, l_app_dt, l_src_cd
 FROM TABLE (xmlsequence( EXTRACT(p_xml,'NewBusinessApplication') )) x;
```

I am using this query to fetch data from xml file but I don't know how to fetch data from a xml file which contains namespaces.
Any help I have tried lots of ways but its not helping me !!

Comment: Spend some time reading the [documentatation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions054.htm)  There is a 3rd, optional parameter to specify one or more namespace strings.

Comment: yes that's what I need to figure out..and now I am tired of reading

Answer (score 0):

Extract and Extractvalue functions have last optional argument `namespace_string`, you can use it to pass namespaces and prefixes you will use in XPath, e.g. `'xmlns:ns1="some/namespace1" xmlns:ns2="some/namespace2"'`.

I prefer this solution:

```
SELECT applno,
       appl_date,
       src_cd
FROM XMLTable(xmlnamespaces (
              'some/namespace1' as "ns1",
              'some/namespace2' as "ns2",
              'some/namespace3' as "ns3"),
            '/ns1:NewBusinessApplications/ns1:NewBusinessApplication' passing
            xmltype('<n1:NewBusinessApplications xmlns:n1="some/namespace1"  xmlns:n2="some/namespace2"  xmlns:n3="some/namespace3">
                       <n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                         <n2:TransactionHeader>
                           <n2:SRC_SYS_CD>src sys cd 1</n2:SRC_SYS_CD>
                         </n2:TransactionHeader>
                         <ApplicationRq>
                           <n3:ApplInfo>
                             <APPLNO>applno 1</APPLNO>
                             <APPL_DT>appl dt 1</APPL_DT>
                           </n3:ApplInfo>
                         </ApplicationRq>
                       </n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                       <n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                         <n2:TransactionHeader>
                           <n2:SRC_SYS_CD>src sys cd 2</n2:SRC_SYS_CD>
                         </n2:TransactionHeader>
                         <ApplicationRq>
                           <n3:ApplInfo>
                             <APPLNO>applno 2</APPLNO>
                             <APPL_DT>appl dt 2</APPL_DT>
                           </n3:ApplInfo>
                         </ApplicationRq>
                       </n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                     </n1:NewBusinessApplications>') columns
            applno VARCHAR2(100) path 'ApplicationRq/ns3:ApplInfo/APPLNO',
            appl_date VARCHAR2(100) path 'ApplicationRq/ns3:ApplInfo/APPL_DT',
            src_cd VARCHAR2(100) path 'ns2:TransactionHeader/ns2:SRC_SYS_CD')
```

Here is your query:

```
SELECT extractvalue(Value(x),
                    'ns1:NewBusinessApplication/ApplicationRq/ns3:ApplInfo/APPLNO/text()',
                    'xmlns:ns1="some/namespace1" xmlns:ns3="some/namespace3"') AS applno
      ,extractvalue(Value(x),
                    'ns1:NewBusinessApplication/ApplicationRq/ns3:ApplInfo/APPL_DT/text()',
                    'xmlns:ns1="some/namespace1" xmlns:ns3="some/namespace3"') AS appl_date
      ,extractvalue(Value(x),
                    'ns1:NewBusinessApplication/ns2:TransactionHeader/ns2:SRC_SYS_CD/text()',
                    'xmlns:ns1="some/namespace1" xmlns:ns2="some/namespace2"') AS src_cd
FROM TABLE (xmlsequence(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<n1:NewBusinessApplications xmlns:n1="some/namespace1"  xmlns:n2="some/namespace2"  xmlns:n3="some/namespace3">
                       <n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                         <n2:TransactionHeader>
                           <n2:SRC_SYS_CD>src sys cd 1</n2:SRC_SYS_CD>
                         </n2:TransactionHeader>
                         <ApplicationRq>
                           <n3:ApplInfo>
                             <APPLNO>applno 1</APPLNO>
                             <APPL_DT>appl dt 1</APPL_DT>
                           </n3:ApplInfo>
                         </ApplicationRq>
                       </n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                       <n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                         <n2:TransactionHeader>
                           <n2:SRC_SYS_CD>src sys cd 2</n2:SRC_SYS_CD>
                         </n2:TransactionHeader>
                         <ApplicationRq>
                           <n3:ApplInfo>
                             <APPLNO>applno 2</APPLNO>
                             <APPL_DT>appl dt 2</APPL_DT>
                           </n3:ApplInfo>
                         </ApplicationRq>
                       </n1:NewBusinessApplication>
                     </n1:NewBusinessApplications>'), 'ns1:NewBusinessApplications/ns1:NewBusinessApplication', 'xmlns:ns1="some/namespace1"'))) x
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i'll check your solution and will get back to you if I find some issue in execution of the query but it seems very satisfying for what I am looking for a long time

Comment: Hi I am getting ORA-01704: string literal too long
because may be file is too long

Comment: SELECT appl_no
      ,appl_date
      ,src_cd
FROM xmltable(xmlnamespaces(
               'http://www.example.org' AS ns1,
               'http://www.example.org' AS ns2,
               'http://www.example.org' AS ns3 ),
               '/ns1:NewBusinessApplications/ns1:NewBusinessApplication' passing
               xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NewBusinessApplication xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org NewBusinessApplication.xsd"
                        xmlns="http://www.example.org">

Comment: I am not able to paste my whole query here also so I just paste begning part of it. In your query you are using multiple ns whereas in my XML there is only 1 ns so is it right approach that I am using here ??

Comment: Examples are here to show you the way, do not to use them literally. You were using some `p_xml` parameter, so use it. When you have only one namespace then you declare only one in `namespace_string` and in `xmlnamespaces`.